# How move div in jquery

Tags: jquery, duplicates

I want to move a div with jQuery. So what I did is target the div with its name  and then added another div before this. This cause me duplication. I don't know what the issue is.

this is how i did it.

```
jQuery("div[name*='shippingAddress.country_id']").before('<h3 class="checkout-heading">Delivery Address</h3>');
```

complete code:

```
this.initial_setup =function() {
    // move country field to top
    jQuery('#' + this.misc.container_id).find('[name="lastname"]').closest('.field').after(jQuery('#' + this.fields.country_id).closest('.field'));
    // if hide fields is true, move telephone field up
    if (crafty_cfg.hide_fields) {
        jQuery('#' + this.fields.country_id).closest('.field').before(jQuery('#' + this.misc.container_id).find('[name="telephone"]').closest('.field'));
    }

    jQuery("div[name*='shippingAddress.country_id']").before('<h3 class="checkout-heading">Delivery Address</h3>');

    // jQuery('.search-container').before('<h3 class="checkout-heading">Delivery Address</h3>');
    // add link for manual address
    jQuery('.search-bar').after('<a href="JavaScript:Void(0)" id="space-link">Enter address manually</a>');
    jQuery('#space-link').click(function(){
        jQuery('.shipping_cp_address_class').css('display','block');
    })
    // add cp address class to fields and labels so we can easily grab them for the hide fields feature
    var that = this;
    jQuery.each(this.fields, function(index, value) {
        if (value !== that.fields.postcode_id && value !== that.fields.country_id) {
            jQuery('#' + value).closest('.control').addClass(that.misc.prefix + '_cp_address_class');
            jQuery('#' + value).closest('.control').prev('label').addClass(that.misc.prefix + '_cp_address_class');
            if (value == that.fields.address_1_id) {
                jQuery('#' + value).closest('.control').parent().closest('.control').addClass(that.misc.prefix + '_cp_address_class');
                jQuery('#' + value).closest('.control').parent().closest('.control').prev('.label').addClass(that.misc.prefix + '_cp_address_class');
            }
        }
    })
}
```

> result: http://prntscr.com/nsb1v8

Comment: did you use this code inside any loop?

Comment: no, not in loop.i have updated the complete section of the code. Please check.

Comment: try `jQuery("div[name='shippingAddress.country_id']")` and check

Comment: still same. i dont what is happening.

Comment: seems like `this.initial_setup` called 2wice anyhow

Comment: is there any way to fix it?